# Eclipse plugin for working with binary file formats

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can anyone point me to an Eclipse plugin for working with complex binary file formats such as TIFF, JPEG, PNG, etc? Ideally the plugin would allow the structure of the binary file to be described in detail and used to decode a file. Features such as structures, logical decisions, int/float/bool/flags expansion.

Comment: So you think that image files are like compiled Java files, with a complete source code in textbased format?

Comment: @Balus:

There is certainly some grouping and logical organization in different binary formats. Any given plugin would have to be specific to the format, though.

Comment: Most binary files have structure such as a header, data records, etc. Here's an example of a commercial tool that does what I am looking for: http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/

Comment: Here's an example template for TIFF file format for 010Editor - http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates/files/TIFTemplate.bt